# Div's not occupying full width on dekstop

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive webpage without the help of any framework. Its pretty basic.

### Desktop view:

All of the 3 div's should display next to each other.

### Tablet view:

the first two div's display on the first row while the other one displays on the second, occupying the the full width.

### Mobile view:

Each div occupies the full width.

### Problem:

On the desktop, the the first two div's appear on the same row while the 3rd doesn't.

Below is my code.

### HTML

```
<h1>Our Menu<h1>
<div class="chicken">
chicken
</div>
<div class="beef">
beef
</div>
<div class="sushi">
sushi
</div>
```

### CSS

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
.chicken,.beef, .sushi{
    padding:0 15px;
    margin:0px;
}

 @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .chicken,.beef,.sushi{
        width:33.333333333333333333%;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .chicken,.beef,.sushi{
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    /*
        .sushi{
            width:100%;
        }
   */
}
 @media screen and(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .chicken,.beef{
        width:50%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

### Fiddle:

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dqxjunon/1/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Thats a typo. It needs to be `min-width` and `max-width`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` so that it will include the padding in the width (also the border). Otherwise, `33.33333%` will be slightly too big to fit all 3 divs on one row.

Answer (score 3):

I notice you're using the `33.33333333333%` width.

What this does not take into account is padding/border of the box model; just the content only.

Try setting the `box-sizing: border-box;` as it will then take into account the padding/borders included in the sizing of the box model.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough (at least not intuitive for me, at first sight) your padding is getting in the way.

Instead of

```
.chicken,.beef, .sushi{
    padding:0 15px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Make is zero:

```
.chicken,.beef, .sushi{
    padding:0; /* changed padding to zero (on all sides)*/
    margin:0px;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqxjunon/2/)

**Updated based on comments:**

Update the width to be less than 33.333333% (to give room to the padding)

```
.chicken,.beef,.sushi{
    width:30%; /*adjusted width */
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

**[See updated fiddle 2:](http://jsfiddle.net/dqxjunon/3/)**

Comment: Thanks but I do need padding of 15 pixel in between them.

Comment: then reduce the width? instead of 33.33333% you will need to give it 30% (perhaps less)

Comment: To fix the padding thing, do `box-sizing: border-box`. Then it will include padding (and border) in the width calculation.

Answer (score 0):

just a small thing - you are not closing your h1 tag. It should be:

```
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution besides setting `box-sizing:border-box` and using a lower width value. You could use another div inside each of the existing divs and set padding on *that* div.

Here is an example:

```
<h1>Our Menu<h1>
<div class="chicken">
    <div class="padding">
        chicken
    </div>
</div>
<div class="beef">
    <div class="padding">
        beef
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sushi">
    <div class="padding">
        sushi
    </div>
</div>
```

And then your css would look like this:

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
.chicken,.beef, .sushi{
    padding:0;
    margin:0px;
}
.padding {
    padding:0 15px;
}

 @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .chicken,.beef,.sushi{
        width:33.333333333333333333%;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .chicken,.beef,.sushi{
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    /*
        .sushi{
            width:100%;
        }
   */
}
 @media screen and(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .chicken,.beef{
        width:50%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```